# Solve $x^2 - \frac{1}{\ln(x) - 1} + \frac{1}{x^2(\ln(x)-1)} = 0$

Tags: logarithms, roots

How would I find the roots of this function?

\begin{equation}
x^2 - \frac{1}{\ln(x) - 1} + \frac{1}{x^2(\ln(x)-1)} = 0
\end{equation}

I don't really know how i would tackle this problem because we're working with natural logarithms. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plot the fuction, you see solutions around $x=1$ and $x=3$ from which you can start Newton method.

You can have *approximations* using series expansions.

Around $x=0$, 
$$x^2 - \frac{1}{\ln(x) - 1} + \frac{1}{x^2(\ln(x)-1)} = 1+4 (x-1)+O\left((x-1)^3\right)$$ and then the solution is close to 
$$x=\frac{3}4$$

Around $x=3$, the expansion would be
$$\left(9-\frac{8}{9 (\log (3)-1)}\right)+\frac{2 (x-3) \left(86+81 \log ^2(3)-163
   \log (3)\right)}{27 (\log (3)-1)^2}+O\left((x-3)^2\right)$$ and the the solution is close to
$$x=\frac{3 \left(83+81 \log ^2(3)-156 \log (3)\right)}{2 \left(86+81 \log ^2(3)-163
   \log (3)\right)}\approx 3.00039$$

**Edit**

With regard to the first root, you could have better and better rational approximations building the $[1,n]$ Padé approximant. This would give 
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & x_{(n)} &  x_{(n)} \approx \\
 1 &  \frac{3}{4} &  0.750000 \\
 2 &  \frac{25}{33} &  0.757576 \\
 3 &  \frac{1247}{1643} &  0.758977   \\
 4 &  \frac{5179}{6822} &  0.759162    \\
 5 &  \frac{11947}{15737} &  0.759166   \\
 6 &  \frac{1339361}{1764260} &    0.759163
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: By a numeric method we find $$x\approx 0.75916167335311382164$$ or $$x\approx 3.00039175573599420937$$

Comment: I've used WolframAlpha which also gave this sollution, but i was wondering if there was an analytic solution for this because solving this equation was necessary to solve a part of a question on my exam.

Comment: Either the person who made  the exam made a mistake, or solving the equation explicitly was **not** required.

Comment: I've asked the full question in a new thread you can find here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3078569/solving-lnx-1y-frac1xy-frac1x2y-frac-lnx-12 the question is about differential equations.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do a quick plot like Plot[x^2-1/(Log[x]-1)+1/(x^2(Log[x]-1)),{x,-10,+10}] which shows the above roots quickly and that there are no others.